# RavenDB Northwind import from SQL - Why is employee_privileges not given a collection?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ravendb, ravendb-studio

Recently I've been playing around with RavenDB. I have specifically been testing  its ability to import from a MySQL database, in this case, a Northwind dataset (specifically, the dataset provided from this link: https://github.com/dalers/mywind)

In RavenStudio, I decided to import from SQL (local MySQL database) into RavenDB. The only table that did not get imported as its own collection was the employee_privileges table. Instead, it exists as a property (key-value pair) in relevant documents. I'm just curious as to the reason why?

When I query the employee_privileges table through MySQL, I receive the following result set:

```
MariaDB [northwind]> select * from employee_privileges;
+-------------+--------------+
| employee_id | privilege_id |
+-------------+--------------+
|           2 |            2 |
+-------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any insight into this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL data model allows nested arrays/objects. In SQL it is rendered as additional table. In some cases such table is not natural and it is created to satisfy 3rd normal form.
In your example employee_privileges gets embedded. It solves select n+1 problem.
You can leave it as a collection instead of embedding it. Find more info on following page.

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/studio/database/tasks/import-data/import-from-sql#import-from-sql